# error getting the text box value in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js, I am trying to write a simple todo list application in which I can update the task. whenever I click on edit button the text box enables for editing and I send a new value to the server via HTTP request but I can not get the new value in angular js .

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in tasks.tasks">
    <td> // user.uid // </td>
    <td >  <input type="text" id="ddd" name="updatedText" ng-model="user.taskname"  ng-disabled="!disable"  value="//user.taskname//">
<input type="image" ng-hide="okbtnstatus" ng-click="updateIt()"  src="static/img/okbtn.png"  height="15px" width="18px" name="editId" value="//user.uid//">
```

Here is my Angular  code

```
$scope.updateIt = function(){

    var data = $scope.user.taskname
    alert(data)
    $http({
        method: "PUT",
        url:"item/"+data
    }).then(function mySuccess(response){
        alert("Updated!!!")
    }, 
        function myError(response){
            alert("error occurred")
        });
 }
```

Here I do not get the updated value in data variable. Please help.

Comment: when do you want to get updated value?

Comment: when I click on the ok button. I want to execute updateIt() function.

Comment: What is your PUT method doing? If it updates and sends a response, assign it back to $scope.user.taskname . Else, how does angular know that the scope value has changed?

Comment: @VijayMenon PUT method updates the value in database. I am using Flask RESTful APIs. I can assign the response back to $scope.user.taskname but I am not able to send the updated value in first place. The alert(data) shows me nothing.

Comment: I've created fiddle for it and it's showing data in alert : http://jsfiddle.net/wm1py3k9/

Comment: your ng-click function "updateit()" doesnt have parameter in HTML, but has parameter "user" in JS. You have to pass the paramter in HTML so that the updateIT() function is called.

Comment: Are you correctly defining controller and setting back in html ?

Comment: @VijayMenon yes I uploaded the wrong version of the code. I edited it.

Comment: Should have told this in the earlier comment . I missed it . The "user" is not the scope variable . It's "tasks" right ? You are calling ng-click inside iteration . So you have to pass "user" to updateIt() and then work on it .

Comment: @AkashKC Thanks I implemented that in my code but it is not working and one more thing I would like to add that there are multiple text boxes so sending the user object as a parameter will work? I tried sending both user and user.taskname but did not get the result

Comment: @VijayMenon Yes I tried that I did `updateIt(user)` and `$scope.updateIt = function(user){ var data = $scope.user.taskname } ` but it did not work.

Comment: @prasanna, we need to see your   complete code to debug further . Please create a plunker or fiddle so that we can help you .

Comment: @VijayMenon Yes I created. Here it is [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/xGiwr6HttOJL8iYcwS1P?p=info)

Comment: @Prasanna I don't see where you're setting $scope.user. You're not using the user you passed on the event handler of your ng-click. 

You should probably use user.taskName there.

Comment: @Nathan When I do so , I get "undefined" in the alert box.

Comment: Can you log what user is being passed on your updateIt method?

Comment: @Nathan when I do `console.log(data)` it shows me undefined in the console too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not see where in your code `$scope.user` is being set, but definitely, this is going to show the selected `user`.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in tasks.tasks">
    <td> // user.uid // </td>
    <td> <input type="button" ng-click="updateIt(user)" value="//user.uid//"/> </td>
</tr>
```

The function will receive the user

```
$scope.updateIt = function(user){
    var data = user.taskname;
    alert(data);
 }
```

Inside the function we use `var data = user.taskname;`, using `$scope.user.taskname` will give unexpected result though, say that because we can't see where `$scope.user` is set.

Hope it helps get you on the right path.